# Getting the right window of "CtrlNotifySink"

Tags: c#, winapi, icons

I tried to get a hold on the icons of any folder, by going down this window tree:

1. CabinetWClass
2. ShellTabWindowClass
3. DUIViewWndClassName
4. DirectUIHWND
5. CtrlNotifySink
6. SHELLDLL_DefView
7. DirectUIHWND

however, I am stuck in DirectUIHWND, because there are more than one child with the class name "CtrlNotifySink".
I need to get a hold on a specific "CtrlNotifySink".. the one that have the child "SHELLDLL_DefView".

how can I do it?

Thanks,
Aviad S.

Answer (score 0):

You might be going about this the wrong way.

If you want to find out what folder windows the user has open, and look at the items within them, take a look at the [scriptable shell objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776890.aspx). The examples on MSDN are mainly in VB and Javascript, but the approach applies to C# as well.